# How will I use a selected value to display a dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

This has been consuming a lot of my time. Please help me. :(

I've been trying to **get the value of the selected item  without loading the page** and after that **assign it to a php variable** so that I can use it to get a value from my database (sql)

For example, I selected a value from a dropdown box labeled "Subject" and after that I should have a code to get its "Subject Code" from my database and display it in a textbox right after the selecting a subject from "Subject".

--- I have tried javascript, jquery, all I've accomplished to do is to get the selected value and display it but not to have it assigned to a php variable. Please help me :(

Thank You in advance :)

Comment: Without loading the page nothing will happen at all :P

Comment: Ajax call to a php page OnChange event of the "dropdown" box.

Comment: PHP is 'pre-processed', meaning after the page has loaded, the execution ends and variables are removed from memory.

Comment: Is that so? :( Well, what I've been trying to do is impossible? Hehe, sorry I'm just really new to these things. So nothing can make it possible at all? Thank You :)

Comment: Its not impossible, @Goikiu has the solution.  You just need to separate your server-side logic.

Comment: Maybe you should consider to read some programming basics tutorials.

Comment: okay, okay thank you! I will consider what you guys said. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite some time, I have figured out what to do. Actually I got the solution from w3schools :) Thanks for informing me on what to do. :) This is not really my actual program. I just used it for experimenting purposes. Hehe.

Posted this just in case someone wants to find out how to do this also.

**Html with PHP**

```
<?php
    include('connect-db.php');
    echo '<table>';
    $fac="faculty";
            $a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admins WHERE user_type='$fac'") 
                                                    or die(mysql_error());
            echo '<tr>      
                 <td style="font:11pt/30pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000;">Faculty Name: </td>
                 <td>
                    <select name="Faculty_Name" id="Faculty_Name" onchange="myfunction(this.value)"/>';
            $ctrs=0;
            echo '<option value="">--select--</option>';
            while($fname=mysql_fetch_array($a))
            {   

                echo '<option value="'. $fname['fullname'].'"> '.$fname['fullname'].'</option>';

            }           
            echo '</select></td>
                </tr>';

            echo '<tr><td> <p>Faculty Id: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>   </td></tr>';

    echo '</table>';

?>
```

**script**

```
function myfunction(str)
            {
                var xmlhttp;


                if (str.length==0)
                  { 
                  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                  return;
                  } 

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                  }
                else
                  {// code for IE6, IE5
                  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                  {
                  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                    var x = document.getElementById("Faculty_Name").selectedIndex;
                var val = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value;

                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                  }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","dynamic.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
```

**dynamic.php**

```
<?php
include('connect-db.php');
$q=$_REQUEST["q"];
$q2=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
$a = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM admins WHERE fullname='$q2'") or die(mysql_error());
$item=mysql_fetch_array($a);
echo $item['id'];
?>
```