# How to properly enable/disable input boxes when a specific checkbox is checked/unchecked?

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

It just doesn't work the way it does on my separate php file where I first experimented on the code.
I am trying to **enable/disable input boxes when a specific checkbox is checked/unchecked.**
These are my code. Please help me. It's suppose to work right? It has worked on my separate file. But it doesn't when I applied it on my actual coding file.

I can't figure out what's wrong. :(

**html with php (checboxes code)**

```
echo '<table style="border-radius:6px;border-color: FFFFFF;width:700; text-align:center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">

<tr><th style="font:11pt/15pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; ">
**<input type="checkbox" name="mon" id="mon" value="Monday" onclick="javascript:Mon_Select()"/>** Monday</th>

<th style="font:11pt/15pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; ">
**<input type="checkbox" name="tues" id="tues" value="Tuesday" onclick="javascript:Tues_Select()">** Tuesday</th>

<th style="font:11pt/15pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; ">
**<input type="checkbox" name="wed" id="wed" value="Wednesday" onclick="javascript:Wed_Select()">** Wednesday</th>

<th style="font:11pt/15pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; ">
**<input type="checkbox" name="thurs" id="thurs" value="Thursday" onclick="javascript:Thurs_Select()">** Thursday</th>

<th style="font:11pt/15pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; ">
**<input type="checkbox" name="fri" id="fri" value="Friday" onclick="javascript:Fri_Select()">** Friday</th>

<th style="font:11pt/15pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; ">
**<input type="checkbox" name="sat" id="sat" value="Saturday" onclick="javascript:Sat_Select()">** Saturday</th>
</tr>
```

**These are the input boxes I want to enable/disable**

```
         <td>
         <label for id="Start_Mon" style="font:9pt/11pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">Start Time: <br>
         <input type="time" style="width:100; height:20" name="Start_Mon" id="Start_Mon" disabled/></label>
         </td>
         <td>
         <label for id="Start_Tues" style="font:9pt/11pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">Start Time: <br>
         <input type="time" style="width:100; height:20" name="Start_Tues" id="Start_Tues" disabled/></label>
         </td><td>
         <label for id="Start_Wed" style="font:9pt/11pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">Start Time: <br>
         <input type="time" style="width:100; height:20" name="Start_Wed" id="Start_Wed" disabled/></label>
         </td>
         <td>
         <label for id="Start_Thurs" style="font:9pt/11pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">Start Time: <br>
         <input type="time" style="width:100; height:20" name="Start_Thurs" id="Start_Thurs" disabled/></label>
         </td>
         <td>
         <label for id="Start_Fri" style="font:9pt/11pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">Start Time: <br>
         <input type="time" style="width:100; height:20" name="Start_Fri" id="Start_Fri" disabled/></label>
         </td>
         <td>
         <label for id="Start_Sat" style="font:9pt/11pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">Start Time: <br>
         <input type="time" style="width:100; height:20" name="Start_Sat" id="Start_Sat" disabled/></label>
         </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

         <td>
         <label for id="End_Mon" style="font:9pt/11pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">End Time: <br>
         <input type="time" style="width:100; height:20" name="End_Mon" id="End_Mon" disabled/></label>
         </td>
         <td>
         <label for id="End_Tues" style="font:9pt/11pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">End Time: <br>
         <input type="time" style="width:100; height:20" name="End_Tues" id="End_Tues" disabled/></label>
         </td><td>
         <label for id="End_Wed" style="font:9pt/11pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">End Time: <br>
         <input type="time" style="width:100; height:20" name="End_Wed" id="End_Wed" disabled/></label>
         </td>
         <td>
         <label for id="End_Thurs" style="font:9pt/11pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">End Time: <br>
         <input type="time" style="width:100; height:20" name="End_Thurs" id="End_Thurs" disabled/></label>
         </td>
         <td>
         <label for id="End_Fri" style="font:9pt/11pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">End Time: <br>
         <input type="time" style="width:100; height:20" name="End_Fri" id="End_Fri" disabled/></label>
         </td>
         <td>
         <label for id="End_Sat" style="font:9pt/11pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">End Time: <br>
         <input type="time" style="width:100; height:20" name="End_Sat" id="End_Sat" disabled/></label>
         </td>

    </tr>';



echo '      <tr>    ';  
    $a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rooms ORDER BY room_name ASC") 
                                or die(mysql_error());
echo '          <td>
        <Label for id="Room_Mon" style="font:9pt/11pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">Room:<br>
        <select name="Room_Mon" id="Room_Mon"disabled/>';
        echo '<option value="0">--select--</option>';
        while($rname=mysql_fetch_array($a))
        {

            echo '<option value='.$rname['room_name'].'> '.$rname['room_name'].'</option>';

        }           

        echo '</select></label></td>';

    $a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rooms ORDER BY room_name ASC") 
                                or die(mysql_error());
echo '          <td>
        <Label for id="Room_Tues" style="font:9pt/11pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">Room:<br>
        <select name="Room_Tues" id="Room_Tues" disabled/>';
        echo '<option value="0">--select--</option>';
        while($rname=mysql_fetch_array($a))
        {

            echo '<option value='.$rname['room_name'].'> '.$rname['room_name'].'</option>';

        }           

        echo '</select></label></td>';

    $a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rooms ORDER BY room_name ASC") 
                                or die(mysql_error());
echo '          <td>
        <Label for id="Room_Wed" style="font:9pt/11pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">Room:<br>
        <select name="Room_Wed" id="Room_Wed" disabled/>';
        echo '<option value="0">--select--</option>';
        while($rname=mysql_fetch_array($a))
        {

            echo '<option value='.$rname['room_name'].'> '.$rname['room_name'].'</option>';

        }           

        echo '</select></label></td>';

    $a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rooms ORDER BY room_name ASC") 
                                or die(mysql_error());
echo '          <td>
        <Label for id="Room_Thurs" style="font:9pt/11pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">Room:<br>
        <select name="Room_Thurs" id="Room_Thurs" disabled/>';
        echo '<option value="0">--select--</option>';
        while($rname=mysql_fetch_array($a))
        {

            echo '<option value='.$rname['room_name'].'> '.$rname['room_name'].'</option>';

        }           

        echo '</select></label></td>';

    $a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rooms ORDER BY room_name ASC") 
                                or die(mysql_error());
echo '          <td>
        <Label for id="Room_Fri" style="font:9pt/11pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">Room:<br>
        <select name="Room_Fri" id="Room_Fri" disabled/>';
        echo '<option value="0">--select--</option>';
        while($rname=mysql_fetch_array($a))
        {

            echo '<option value='.$rname['room_name'].'> '.$rname['room_name'].'</option>';

        }           

        echo '</select></label></td>';

    $a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rooms ORDER BY room_name ASC") 
                                or die(mysql_error());
echo '          <td>
        <Label for id="Room_Sat" style="font:9pt/11pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">Room:<br>
        <select name="Room_Sat" id="Room_Sat" disabled/>';
        echo '<option value="0">--select--</option>';
        while($rname=mysql_fetch_array($a))
        {

            echo '<option value='.$rname['room_name'].'> '.$rname['room_name'].'</option>';

        }           

        echo '</select></label></td>';



echo '      </tr>'; 
echo '</table>';


echo '<table style="border-radius:6px;border-color: FFFFFF;width:700; text-align:center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">';
```

**script**

```
<script>

//checkboxes
function Mon_Select()
{
    if (document.getElementById('mon').checked)
        {
        document.getElementById('Start_Mon').disabled= false;
        document.getElementById('End_Mon').disabled= false;
        document.getElementById('Room_Mon').disabled= false;}
    else
        {
        document.getElementById('Start_Mon').disabled= true;
        document.getElementById('End_Mon').disabled= true;
        document.getElementById('Room_Mon').disabled= true;}
}   
 function Tues_Select()
{
    if (document.getElementById('tues').checked)
        {
        document.getElementById('Start_Tues').disabled= false;
        document.getElementById('End_Tues').disabled= false;
        document.getElementById('Room_Tues').disabled= false;}
    else
        {
        document.getElementById('Start_Tues').disabled= true;
        document.getElementById('End_Tues').disabled= true;
        document.getElementById('Room_Tues').disabled= true;}
}
 function Wed_Select()
{
    if (document.getElementById('wed').checked)
        {
        document.getElementById('Start_Wed').disabled= false;
        document.getElementById('End_Wed').disabled= false;
        document.getElementById('Room_Wed').disabled= false;}
    else
        {
        document.getElementById('Start_Wed').disabled= true;
        document.getElementById('End_Wed').disabled= true;
        document.getElementById('Room_Wed').disabled= true;}
}
 function Thurs_Select()
{
    if (document.getElementById('thurs').checked)
        {
        document.getElementById('Start_Thurs').disabled= false;
        document.getElementById('End_Thurs').disabled= false;
        document.getElementById('Room_Thurs').disabled= false;}
    else
        {
        document.getElementById('Start_Thurs').disabled= true;
        document.getElementById('End_Thurs').disabled= true;
        document.getElementById('Room_Thurs').disabled= true;}
}
 function Fri_Select()
{
    if (document.getElementById('fri').checked)
        {
        document.getElementById('Start_Fri').disabled= false;
        document.getElementById('End_Fri').disabled= false;
        document.getElementById('Room_Fri').disabled= false;}
    else
        {
        document.getElementById('Start_Fri').disabled= true;
        document.getElementById('End_Fri').disabled= true;
        document.getElementById('Room_Fri').disabled= true;}
}
 function Sat_Select()
{
    if (document.getElementById('sat').checked)
        {
        document.getElementById('Start_Sat').disabled= false;
        document.getElementById('End_Sat').disabled= false;
        document.getElementById('Room_Sat').disabled= false;}
    else
        {
        document.getElementById('Start_Sat').disabled= true;
        document.getElementById('End_Sat').disabled= true;
        document.getElementById('Room_Sat').disabled= true;}
}   



</script>
```

Comment: ask me if something confuses you. My code is a bit messy. But it's easy to understand.

Comment: Could you reduce it to the simple minimum that has the problem?

Comment: Also possible duplicate material with your previous question: [Assigning selected option html to a php variable without loading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048115/assigning-selected-option-html-to-a-php-variable-without-loading-the-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this in your html:

```
onclick="javascript:Mon_Select()"
```

just do this:

```
onclick="Mon_Select()"
```

The first one isn't valid js code (only works in urls), the second one works.

**EDIT** Also, remove your `id` attributes from your `<labels>` as sanjeev suggests

Hope this helps, cheers

Comment: Okay sir, but I've tried that already. And the first one, works perfectly on my other php file. I'm still going to try your suggestion :) Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you sir :) I'm going to do that:)

Comment: I hope you can mark my answer as accepted ;)

Comment: I just did :) haha, sorry im just new here. Thanks It really worked :)

Comment: Welcome! Glad it helped. Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Answer (score 1):

```
                         <td>
                         <label for id="Start_Mon" style="font:9pt/11pt Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;">Start Time: <br>
                         <input type="time" style="width:100; height:20" name="Start_Mon" id="Start_Mon" disabled/></label>
                         </td>
```

you are giving id ='Start_Mon' to a label
you should give it to input element that is

```
<input type="time" id='Start_Mon' style="width:100; height:20" name="Start_Mon" id="Start_Mon" disabled/></label>
```

Change it for all in above code

id need to be given to input field and not label

not more clarification do ask!!!

Comment: Thank you sir, I shall try that :)